# How to change the default highlight color of a property in the Aptana-pydev?

Tags: python, text-editors, syntax-highlighting, ide

The default text highlighting and default font colors that came with Aptana (Eclipse) seems to be a little wacky, anyone have any idea how to fix this?

This example isn't the only place where stuff like this happens.  The editor is trying to make my life easier by highlighting use of the same variable, but its actually making it so that I can't see the variable at all.

I feel like some of the default text editor settings are in conflict?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not a bug. May be a quirk in the way default colors are setup, but not a bug. I see you're using Aptana 3 on Windows. Why don't you just change the theme?

```
Window -> Preferences -> Aptana -> Themes
```

Pick a different theme like Aptana Studio 2.x or adjust your colors for this theme.

Comment: jajajajaja +1 @DutrowLLC I hate it too, jajaja update Aptana they change the color in the new version.

Comment: just restoring defaults helped in my case..

Answer (score 2):

Click the "Apply editor font to views" on then apply;
If it's already on, turn it off fist then apply, and on again.

Answer (score 0):

The particular background colour shown in the picture is controlled by windows-> preferences-> General->Editors->Annotations->Occurrences.

Is it used by pydev->editor->mark occurrences.

That's one hour of my life I'm not getting back.